# ES6 constructor destructuring

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6

I know you can do object destructuring in ES6 but I was wondering if there is a clever solution for constructor destructuring so I can skip the manual assignment like below and instead do something like the hypothetical scenario. I know it is dangerous and unreliable to accept everything in constructor, but just curious.

```
// Hypothetical 
constructor(... args){
 object.assign(this,...args);
}

constructor(pieceName,pieceImage,dataAttribute,numeric,ascii){
        this.pieceName = piecename; 
        this.pieceImage = pieceImage; 
        this.dataAttribu

}
```

Comment: Seems like a major headache if you want to reference properties.

Comment: `[...args]` is pointless, `args` already is an array.

Comment: You can use `Object.assign(this, {pieceName, pieceImage, dataAttribute})`

Comment: @Bergi won't the spread ...args do that ?

Comment: Does your constructor expect an object or multiple parameters? In the latter case there's not much you can do (if you don't want to resort to dark magic)

Comment: multiple parameters..

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I meant `[...args]` = `args`

Comment: @Bergi thank you. Got it.